# Do I have a memory leak in my ASP.NET Core 2.2 application?

Tags: memory-leaks, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm not really experienced with ASP.NET Core. I was tasked to do some website that does automation but I'm having problems with the memory consumption. In time the application seems like doesn't release any memory and everytime when I refresh some page the memory usage goes up and up. And also this is my first time using dependency injection. And used transient services for all of it. Can that be relatin. Here's one of snapshot I've take.

[image: Text]